# Decompiled Java class missing Final Keyword on method variable

Tags: java, final

I decompiled my Java Class which had final variable within methods. I did notice that all the Final Keywords within Methods variables weren't present, why?

Comment: The point in keeping them would be ...?

Comment: And how did you decompile?

Comment: `final` is a compile-time guarantee that is most useful as a promise to other programmers. "I promise I won't change this variable ever once it's initialized". The runtime has no use for it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That is only partly true. While it may be irrelevant at exeuction time, it should be present in class file format. Otherwise, there would be no way to enforce that `final` fields, methods, classes... in a precompiled library are not overridden.

Comment: But that isn't a real answer. One would have to look into the Java language or byte code specifications to determine whether this is "works as designed" or maybe a problem of the decompiler to ignore corresponding meta information.

Comment: @Turing85 Fair. But this question is about local variables, which will never be overridden.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo touché =)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That makes a lot of sense. However, I didn't mention that the `final` for the class variables were presence. Will those have any use at runtime? — Thanks

Comment: @B0BAI you should always think of `final` as some promise, not a hard protection (at least, when we are talking about the field modifier). You can change the value of a final field via reflection. This even works in C(++) where you can "change" the value of a `const` field and get funny results, suggesting that you stored two different values in the same memory location.

Comment: @GhostCat I used IntelliJ.

Comment: Well, reflection prior Java 9 and modules. The times when everything was wide open at runtime are gone, at least to a certain extent.

Comment: @Turing85 Make sense! Thanks for explaining further.